# Format part of a cell formula string as hyperlink

Tags: google-sheets

Link to my dummy spreadsheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1luNznudza_bSYX4TbDyJ4AG6UtHL8T5YQ3l_aFvET9E/edit#gid=0).

I need to partially format a cell by making a specific string set to a hyperlink found within another cell. I am currently nesting the hyperlink function within a `=REGEXREPLACE` function. Very messy and requires an extra cell. **Example:**

```
=Regexreplace(B12,"Story Plan assignment", HYPERLINK(D12, "Story Plan Assignment"))
```

The above code is currently doing everything correctly, except that it replaces "Story Plan Assignment" from a different cell, but without carrying the hyperlink.

**Here is what I actually want to do:**

**Cell 1:** string here, but find a word within the string and make that word have the hyperlink that is in cell 2
**Cell 2:** hyperlink

If this can only be done populating a third cell, like I did with my first function, that's fine. Can I embed a function within a string"

Comment: You can't embed hyperlink formula inside another one like that. But... I don't understand your problem. Could you provide a piece of your real sheet?

Comment: I hear you, so might I be able to do this using multiple cells? Here is my sheet, you'll see the description of what I want to do: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1luNznudza_bSYX4TbDyJ4AG6UtHL8T5YQ3l_aFvET9E/edit#gid=0

Comment: Access Denied ... Make your file "more" public ;)

Comment: Just made public--sorry!

Comment: Sorry... it is impossible to achieve something like that - a Hyperlink inside running text is not supported by Google Sheets (as far as I know) :( Only single cell (entire) can be used as a link / hypertext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry... it is impossible to achieve something like that - a Hyperlink inside running text is not supported by Google Sheets (as far as I know) :( Only single cell (entire) can be used as a link / hypertext

Comment: Thank you so much, Grzegorz--this is the answer then!